# Windmills generate electricity by the spinning blades. Why can't EV vehicles recharge their batteries from their spinning wheels? Is that too hard?

Tags: power-supply, power, battery-charging, automotive, charging

I'm just a carpenter who's job it is to find the easiest answers to the biggest problems. I don't know much about EV vehicles, but this sounds like a no brainer. So there must be a specific reason as to why this isn't possible, standard, and mandatory. Thanks in advance for your knowledge.

Comment: Where does the energy which makes the wheels spin come from?

Comment: My tesla actually recharges the batteries several percent when I drive down out of the mountains, so it certainly does recharge from the motion of the vehicle,  at least until sea level.

Comment: @user1850479 And when you drive up them? :P

Comment: I think we should put a windmill of the roof to recharge the batteries whilst driving. That’s what Wil.e.Coyote would do.

Comment: Because law of conservation of energy doesn't like that idea. The energy to rotate the wheels originated from the battery itself. Otherwise you need energy to be converted from some other source, say for eg: potential energy due to gravity.... a vehicle moving freely down the hill can make use of the concept you said.

Comment: Can't answer. But it's been done. https://www.wired.com/story/this-huge-electric-dump-truck-never-needs-to-plug-in/ The trick is, drive up the mountain empty, and drive down full, and the extra weight charges the batteries (via regenerative braking) enough for the next uphill trip.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

They do. It's called [regenerative braking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regenerative_braking).

The only time you can practically recover energy from the wheels is during braking. Taking energy from them slows them down. If you do it while they are being powered by the motors, you're just making the motors work harder. If you do it while coasting, the vehicle will quickly slow down and the driver will need to accelerate.

Answer (score 3):

The motion of a car is a form of energy, and to get the car moving in the first place that energy had to come from somewhere, either fuel or batteries.

If your car is electric, energy stored in the batteries (called "chemical potential energy") is converted into motion by electric motors. Some energy, however never makes to becoming motion, some is wasted overcoming electrical resistance in the wires on the way to the motors, some is wasted overcoming friction between the wheels and road, some is wasted moving air out of the way of the car, and so on. All this wasted energy ends up eventually as heat somewhere, and isn't usable any more by the car.

There is a physical law called "conservation of energy", which says that energy is never lost, is just gets transformed from one form to another, like heat, or motion, or light. If you add up all the various quantities of energy in its various forms and places in the system of vehicle and world, you find that the total never changes, due to the law of conservation of energy. The whole system is a perfect "energy accountant". Energy just gets moved around, never created or destroyed. There's no "inflation" or "interest" in this accounting system, no potential for profit or loss, it's penny-precise accounting, always.

Some of the energy, as I mentioned is wasted. Not "lost", just changed to a form (heat) that we can no longer control, or convert back into a form we can re-use (like putting it back in the battery). Once it becomes heat, it's as good as gone to us. However, before it becomes heat, we have the technology still to manipulate it. For instance, the energy of the forward motion of the car, and the spinning motion of the wheels, called "kinetic energy", can still be "captured" and converted back into chemical potential energy inside the battery.

The recovery process is also imperfect, and no matter how hard we try to make the conversion as efficient as possible, some energy will still be wasted (converted to heat) in that recovery process. That recovery process in electric vehicles cars is called "regenerative braking", but it is not 100% efficient.

Remember always that all energy is accounted for, perfectly. This means if the car is speeding up, the energy in the battery must be depleting. If we recover energy from the car's/wheel's motion, the battery may be charging again, but the car must be slowing down. The law of conservation of energy means that the best we can hope to achieve is a 100% efficient conversion between battery energy and motion energy, or back, but the total amount of energy available in the system to do this is limited to the total energy we put in the battery in the first place! The battery/car system is a reservoir of a fixed and limited amount of energy, and our aim is simply to move energy within that limited resource back and forth between battery charge and vehicle motion.

In reality we can never achieve 100% efficient conversion from any form to any other form of energy, heat is always generated in the process, which eventually finds it's way into the environment where it's of no use to us. For every 100 watt-hours of energy you remove from the battery to make motion, perhaps 10Wh becomes unrecoverable heat, and 90Wh becomes recoverable motion. This means that usable energy reserves dwindle over time, as heat energy is radiated out of the system.

To get to your question, which was about recharging the vehicle's battery from the energy of its motion, we already do that, with regenerative braking.  However, what I aimed to clarify here is that any energy we put back into the battery in doing so, came from the battery in the first place to accelerate the car, and isn't something you "get for free" from the world (unless you're driving down hill, in which case you *do* have gravity providing a free "top up"). It's all energy from the reserve that you provided by initially charging the car's battery before you left home.

I hope it's also clearer now, that because of inefficiencies in the energy conversions that take place, the total energy stored in various forms in car's system (battery charge and motion) diminishes over time, and that's why you have to keep topping up the battery with energy from the grid.

Therefore, yes, it's possible to charge the battery with energy from the spinning of wheels and forward motion of the car, but that's only energy you had to provide in the first place, and by recovering it, necessarily they must slow down, in accordance with the law of conservation of energy.

Let me illustrate this with an example.

You charge your battery at home with 10,000 watt-hours of energy. Then you accelerate the car to 100kph. This requires that you withdraw 1000 watt-hours of energy from the battery, and invest that energy into motion. The universe charges you a withdrawal fee, 100 watt-hours, for that privilege, so in reality you only have 900 watt-hours-worth of motion. The 100Wh withdrawal fee is what you would see as heat, unrecoverable, and belonging to the rest of the universe now. The remaining 900Wh is still owned by you, and is manifest as vehicle/wheel motion.

You slow to 0kph, to recover those 900Wh of energy and deposit it back into your battery-bank-account, but the universe charges you a 10% fee, 90Wh for the service. What you have in the battery is now 10,000Wh of energy minus the universal charges of 100wh and 90wh. That's only 9,810Wh.

You only have 9,810Wh of chemical potential energy in your account now, and the universal bank has 190Wh of heat. Penny-precise accounting.

Occasionally the world gives you free money, like a tail-wind, or a downhill slope. It feels good to get a combined 100Wh of gift vouchers, until you realise that you have to drive upwind and uphill again at some point, to get back home. And during the deposit and withdrawal of those watt-hours into and out of your account, the universal bank screws you over again, with additional fees. In fact you had to pay in the long term, for this free lunch. There's never a free lunch. The cake is a lie.